# python pandas - groupby.first() returning NaT values

Tags: python, pandas

I am retrieving the cummax() value of the following dataframe,

```
                     exit_price  trend  netgain     high      low   MFE_pr
exit_time                                                                 
2000-02-01 01:00:00     1400.25     -1     1.00  1401.50  1400.25  1400.25
2000-02-01 01:30:00     1400.75     -1     0.50  1401.00  1399.50  1399.50
2000-02-01 02:00:00     1400.00     -1     1.25  1401.00  1399.75  1399.50
2000-02-01 02:30:00     1399.25     -1     2.00  1399.75  1399.25  1399.25
2000-02-01 03:00:00     1399.50     -1     1.75  1400.00  1399.50  1399.25
2000-02-01 03:30:00     1398.25     -1     3.00  1399.25  1398.25  1398.25
2000-02-01 04:00:00     1398.75     -1     2.50  1399.00  1398.25  1398.25
2000-02-01 04:30:00     1400.00     -1     1.25  1400.25  1399.00  1398.25
2000-02-01 05:00:00     1400.25     -1     1.00  1400.50  1399.25  1398.25
2000-02-01 05:30:00     1400.50     -1     0.75  1400.75  1399.50  1398.25
```

with the following formula

```
trade ['MFE_pr'] = np.nan
trade ['MFE_pr'] = trade ['MFE_pr'].where(trade ['trend']<0, trade.high.cummax())
trade ['MFE_pr'] = trade ['MFE_pr'].where(trade ['trend']>0, trade.low.cummin())
```

Now i want to retrieve the timestamp of the row at which cummax() is taken from for each row.

I have been trying the following:

```
trade['timestamp']= trade.index
trade ['MFE_ts'] = trade.groupby('MFE_pr')['timestamp'].first()
```

but i am receiving as a result:

```
                     exit_price  trend  netgain     high      low   MFE_pr  \
exit_time                                                                    
2000-02-01 01:00:00     1400.25     -1     1.00  1401.50  1400.25  1400.25   
2000-02-01 01:30:00     1400.75     -1     0.50  1401.00  1399.50  1399.50   
2000-02-01 02:00:00     1400.00     -1     1.25  1401.00  1399.75  1399.50   
2000-02-01 02:30:00     1399.25     -1     2.00  1399.75  1399.25  1399.25   
2000-02-01 03:00:00     1399.50     -1     1.75  1400.00  1399.50  1399.25   
2000-02-01 03:30:00     1398.25     -1     3.00  1399.25  1398.25  1398.25   
2000-02-01 04:00:00     1398.75     -1     2.50  1399.00  1398.25  1398.25   
2000-02-01 04:30:00     1400.00     -1     1.25  1400.25  1399.00  1398.25   
2000-02-01 05:00:00     1400.25     -1     1.00  1400.50  1399.25  1398.25   
2000-02-01 05:30:00     1400.50     -1     0.75  1400.75  1399.50  1398.25   

                              timestamp MFE_ts  
exit_time                                       
2000-02-01 01:00:00 2000-02-01 01:00:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 01:30:00 2000-02-01 01:30:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 02:00:00 2000-02-01 02:00:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 02:30:00 2000-02-01 02:30:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 03:00:00 2000-02-01 03:00:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 03:30:00 2000-02-01 03:30:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 04:00:00 2000-02-01 04:00:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 04:30:00 2000-02-01 04:30:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 05:00:00 2000-02-01 05:00:00    NaT  
2000-02-01 05:30:00 2000-02-01 05:30:00    NaT
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, it computes and returns the results of the first value in every group.

```
trade.groupby('MFE_pr')['timestamp'].first()
MFE_pr
1398.25   2000-02-01 03:30:00
1399.25   2000-02-01 02:30:00
1399.50   2000-02-01 01:30:00
1400.25   2000-02-01 01:00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So, when you try to reindex this back to your original `DF`(by assigning this value to a new column), it results in `NaTs` getting created as they do not have a common index to reindex upon:

```
trade.groupby('MFE_pr')['timestamp'].first().reindex(trade.index)
exit_time
2000-02-01 01:00:00   NaT
2000-02-01 01:30:00   NaT
2000-02-01 02:00:00   NaT
2000-02-01 02:30:00   NaT
2000-02-01 03:00:00   NaT
2000-02-01 03:30:00   NaT
2000-02-01 04:00:00   NaT
2000-02-01 04:30:00   NaT
2000-02-01 05:00:00   NaT
2000-02-01 05:30:00   NaT
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) instead which applies these computed values cumulatively to all the rows present in the grouped series thereby keeping the shape of your original `DF` intact:

```
trade['MFE_ts'] = trade.groupby('MFE_pr')['timestamp'].transform('first') 
trade
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need assign to new `DataFrame`,  because `first` aggregate data. If assign new column, because index is created from column `MFE_pr` and original is `DatetimeIndex`, it doesnt match and get `NaT`:

```
trade1 = trade.groupby('MFE_pr', as_index=False)['timestamp'].first() 

print (trade1)
    MFE_pr           timestamp
0  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00
1  1399.25 2000-02-01 02:30:00
2  1399.50 2000-02-01 01:30:00
3  1400.25 2000-02-01 01:00:00
```

You can also use [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for convert `index` to `Series` and then `groupby` by column `MFE_pr`:

```
trade1 = trade.index.to_series().groupby([trade['MFE_pr']]).first().reset_index()
print (trade1)
   MFE_pr           exit_time
0  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00
1  1399.25 2000-02-01 02:30:00
2  1399.50 2000-02-01 01:30:00
3  1400.25 2000-02-01 01:00:00
```

If need column one possible solution is use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) - output is `Series` with same length as original `DataFrame`:

```
trade['MFE_ts'] = trade.index.to_series().groupby([trade['MFE_pr']]).transform('first')

print (trade)
                     exit_price  trend  netgain     high      low   MFE_pr  \
exit_time                                                                    
2000-02-01 01:00:00     1400.25     -1     1.00  1401.50  1400.25  1400.25   
2000-02-01 01:30:00     1400.75     -1     0.50  1401.00  1399.50  1399.50   
2000-02-01 02:00:00     1400.00     -1     1.25  1401.00  1399.75  1399.50   
2000-02-01 02:30:00     1399.25     -1     2.00  1399.75  1399.25  1399.25   
2000-02-01 03:00:00     1399.50     -1     1.75  1400.00  1399.50  1399.25   
2000-02-01 03:30:00     1398.25     -1     3.00  1399.25  1398.25  1398.25   
2000-02-01 04:00:00     1398.75     -1     2.50  1399.00  1398.25  1398.25   
2000-02-01 04:30:00     1400.00     -1     1.25  1400.25  1399.00  1398.25   
2000-02-01 05:00:00     1400.25     -1     1.00  1400.50  1399.25  1398.25   
2000-02-01 05:30:00     1400.50     -1     0.75  1400.75  1399.50  1398.25   

                                 MFE_ts  
exit_time                                
2000-02-01 01:00:00 2000-02-01 01:00:00  
2000-02-01 01:30:00 2000-02-01 01:30:00  
2000-02-01 02:00:00 2000-02-01 01:30:00  
2000-02-01 02:30:00 2000-02-01 02:30:00  
2000-02-01 03:00:00 2000-02-01 02:30:00  
2000-02-01 03:30:00 2000-02-01 03:30:00  
2000-02-01 04:00:00 2000-02-01 03:30:00  
2000-02-01 04:30:00 2000-02-01 03:30:00  
2000-02-01 05:00:00 2000-02-01 03:30:00  
2000-02-01 05:30:00 2000-02-01 03:30:00
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately only one solution will be accepted. So you can chose between my and another solution. It is up to you!